# Changed content type leading to wrong crawls by google

Tags: wordpress, url, google-analytics, indexing, google-crawlers

In our website built on WordPress, we changed name of one of our Custom Post type from 'A' to 'B' and also changed hierarchy of few categories.

Now, the problem is that google is indexing/crawling the old 'A' CPT Name and also old catgeory structure, which is leading to either random pages (*because WordPress makes guess and shows page with those keywords in URL*) or 404 errors.

What can we do (via Webmaster Tools) to make google re-index our whole site and start honoring our new structure? Thanks.

Comment: Adding 301 redirects from the old post type to new post types and from the old hierarchy to the new one.

Comment: Okay, that may be one way. But what if we did lot of changes and we ourselves don't know what category hierarchies we played with?

Comment: You will need to do it manually. Google wouldn't know you changed post type A to B. It's up to you to let them know (with 301 redirects).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the brief explanation of the Google's indexing policy:

**The process**

The crawl process begins with a list of web addresses from past crawls and [sitemaps](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184) provided by website owners. As Google crawlers visit these websites, they look for links for other pages to visit. The software pays special attention to new sites, changes to existing sites and dead links.

Computer programs **determine which sites to crawl**, **how often and how many pages to fetch** from each site. **Google doesn't accept payment to crawl a site more frequently for your web search results**. They care more about having the best possible results  because in the long run that's what's best for users and, therefore, their business.

**Choice for website owners**

Most websites don't need to set up restrictions for crawling, indexing or serving, so their pages are eligible to appear in search results without having to do any extra work.

That said, site owners have many choices about how Google crawls and indexes their sites **through** [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) and a file called “[robots.txt](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=en)”. With the `robots.txt` file, site owners can choose not to be crawled by `Google bot` or they can provide more specific instructions about how to process pages on their sites.

Site owners have granular choices and can choose how content is indexed on a page-by-page basis. For example, they can opt to have their pages appear without a snippet (the summary of the page shown below the title in search results) or a cached version (an alternate version stored on Google's servers in case the live page is unavailable). Web-masters can also choose to integrate search into their own pages with [Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/?hl=en).

Read more [here](http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/insidesearch/howsearchworks/crawling-indexing.html) and [here](http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/insidesearch/howsearchworks/algorithms.html).

Comment: Thanks @bodi0 but I knew how the search works. What I mean to ask was what can be done from our end (via Webmaster Tools) so that google can stat honoring our new structure. As, we've implemented it from long time and google is not recognizing the new structure.

I was wondering if there could be anything that can be done via 'Fetch as Google' or 'Submit Index' or something.